# Simple application of residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Hello I am just trying to learn about the residue theorem is this correct?

\begin{aligned}
&\int_{C} \frac{2z}{z^{2}+2}, C = \gamma^{+}(0;2)\\
&\int_{C} \frac{2z}{z^{2}+2} = \int_{C} \frac{2z}{(z- \sqrt2 i)(z + \sqrt2 i)}   
\end{aligned}
We have two poles $\pm \sqrt2 i$ of order 1.

Hence $res \{ f(z); a \} = lim _{z \rightarrow a} (z-a) f(z)$
So $res \{ f(z); \pm \sqrt2 i \} = 1,1$

Therefore the integral is $2 \pi i (1+1) = 4 \pi i$

Comment: What  does the notation $\gamma^+(0;2)$ mean?

Comment: Circular contour having center 0 and radius 2

Comment: I have deleted my answer. What you did is fine.

Comment: Okay thank you I was worried I mixed up some calculation